# SQL: Add the row values and display in new column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I Have table t1 ordered by tasteRating

```
    Fruit | tasteRating|Cost 
    -----------------------
    Apple |  99       | 1  
    Banana|  87       | 2  
    Cherry|  63       | 5
```

I want t2

```
    Fruit | Cost | Total Cost
    -------------------------
    Apple |   1  | 1
    Banana|   2  | 3
    Cherry|   5  | 8
```

Is there a way to generate Total Cost dynamically in SQL based on value of Cost?
Doing this on Redshift.
Thanks

Comment: No, there is no way with the data you have provided. SQL tables represent unordered sets.  To specify an ordering, you need an additional column, because the data is clearly not ordered by the first column.  Do you have another column with the ordering?

Comment: Added some more detail

Comment: . . You haven't specified a column with the ordering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A running sum like that, can easily be done in a [modern DBMS](http://use-the-index-luke.com/de/blog/2015-02/modern-sql) using window functions:

```
select col_1,
       sum(col_1) over (order by taste_rating desc) as col_2
from the_table;
```

Note however that a running sum without an `order by` doesn't make sense. So you have to include a column that defines the order of the rows.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/166b9/1

EDIT:  (By Gordon)

RedShift has weird limitations on Window functions.  For some reason, it requires the `rows between` syntax:

```
sum(col_1) over (order by taste_rating desc
                 rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                ) as col_2
```

I have no idea why it has this requirement.  It is not required by ANSI (although it is supported) and it is not a limitation in Postgres (the base database for Redshift).

Comment: The database has been added and Redshift supports window functions.

Comment: Getting this- ERROR: Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause

Comment: Documentation here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Examples_of_sum_WF.html. I am getting the total in reverse order, any idea why?

Comment: Solved, I missed the desc in the order by. Thanks.